# Difference in the meaning between "I got him to catch a taxi" and "I had him catch a taxi"?

Tags: prepositions

What is the exact difference in the meaning between "I got him to catch a taxi" and "I had him catch a taxi" ?

Could I use "I got him catch a taxi" instead of "I got him to catch a taxi" ? if so, What is the exact difference in the meaning between "I got him catch a taxi" and "I got him to catch a taxi" ?

(((( i have thought that "I got him catch a taxi" means "I ordered him and he catched a taxi" and that "I got him to catch a taxi" means "I ordered him and he would catch a taxi" and that "I had him catch a taxi" means " I ordered him and he catched a taxi" and that "I had him catching a taxi" mean "I ordered him and he was catching a taxi".  I have Always confused about the time sequence about those.
i have confused whether or not the person who was ordered really did it.

## for examples, i want to ask about my confusing.

A---> John let me drive his new car.

a) I drove his new car.

b) I did not decide whether or not I drove his new car.

B----> She made her children do their homework.

a)  Her children did their homework.
b)  Her children did not decide whether or not they did their homework.

C=====> I had the mechanic check the brakes.

a) The mechanic checked the brakes.
b) The mechanic did not decide whether or not he checked the brakes.

D=====> Susie got her son to take the medicine

a) Her son took the medicine.
b) Her son did not decided whether or not he took the medicine.

E=====> Susie got her son take the medicine

a) Her son took the medicine.
b) Her son did not decided whether or not he took the medicine.

))))))

Could I use "I had him to catch a taxi" as "I got him to catch a taxi" ?

Comment: I have rolled back your question to Version 5. Because starting with Version 6, you asked a completely different question, with a completely changed title.. Please do not edit your answer to ask a completely new question. Post a new question instead.

Comment: This is not a duplicate of *What is the difference between "get my hair cut" or "have my hair cut"*. It could've been if the other question were *What is the difference between "**got him to cut** my hair" or "**had him cut** my hair"*.

Answer (score 1):

The causative verbs let, make, have and get used in the sentences presented by the OP in the second form (past) give an idea that someone caused an action to happen; it's quite clear that the action is complete or finished. I am at loss to understand why he is confused about whether the action is complete or not?

As for the sentence I had him to catch a taxi, it's incorrect grammatically. You use the infinitive without "to" with have in this type of sentence. The correct sentence is I had him catch a taxi.

Regarding the sentences I had my hair cut and I got my hair cut, there's no difference in meaning.  I think the use of get is more idiomatic here.

Answer (score 0):

The verb [get](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/get) in the sense **cause** requires an adjective, passive participle (-ed), an infinitive **with** a to, or an active participle (-ing).

> I got him to catch a taxi

The verb [have](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/have) in the sense **make something happen** requires a passive participle (-ed), an infinitive **without** a to, or an active participle (-ing).

> I had him catch a taxi

There is no significant difference in meaning between the two sentences, although the first (got) is less formal.

Note that we usually only use the word [catch](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/catch) about forms of transport that operate on a time schedule, for example buses, trains or aeroplanes. We normally use the word [take](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/take) for a taxi. **take** can be used for most forms of transport.

Answer (score 0):

There is a slight difference in meaning between your two sentences

> I had him catch a taxi.

means you told him to use a taxi

> I got him to catch a taxi.

means he may have been indecisive on what to use as transportation but you convinced him to use a taxi.

One would usually use "take a taxi", "grab a taxi", or "go by taxi" instead of "catch".

Comment: I had him catch a taxi.===> Me: "Catch a taxi"====> Him: "Wait a minute, i think if i catch a taxi"..

Comment: as a result, did he catch a taxi ? or didn't we know whether or not he caught a taxi?

Comment: you mean that "I got him to catch a taxi.-->we didn't know whether or not he caught a taxi" . if so,  "I had him catch a taxi. --> we didn't know whetehr or not he caught a taxi"? or "I had him catch a taxi --> we knew that he caught a taxi" ?

Comment: In both statements it is assumed "he caught a taxi" since that is what is being reported by the speaker. "I got him to *do something*" is idiomatic "I got him to come over after work." means "I convinced him to come over after work."; "I got him to see our side of the argument." means "I convinced him to understand our side of the argument."